# R Crowd simulation with individual behavior

Tags: r, simulation

When i execute a crowd simulation, all dots start going to the suggested metting point (reffer to the code). However the dots (people leaving the room) start to step over the other dots, something that shouldnt be happening according to my excersice.

Here is the code:

```
dimensionX=10
dimensionY=10
numberPeople=20
velocity=0.001
varianzavelocidad=runif(1, min=0, max=5)
x<-dimensionX*runif(numberPeople)
y<-dimensionY*runif(numberPeople)
plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,dimensionX),ylim=c(0,dimensionY))
for(i in 1:10000) {
    for(j in 1:numberPeople) {
        ang <- atan((y[j]-5)/(10-x[j]))
        x[j]<-x[j]+velocity*varianzavelocidad*cos(ang)
        y[j]<-y[j]-velocity*varianzavelocidad*sin(ang)
    }
    x[x>10]=10
    plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,dimensionX),ylim=c(0,dimensionY)) 
}
```

My thoughts were that i should be working with an If()/Else() condition inside the J array, however am not sure how to read each J object and set a condition that if the dot/point tries to step over another dot/point it would compare a strength value between the dots trying to step over.
A clue of how i would like to make it work:

```
dimensionX=10
dimensionY=10
numberPeople=20
velocity=0.001
strength=runit(1)   *******
varianzavelocidad=runif(1, min=0, max=5)
x<-dimensionX*runif(numberPeople)
y<-dimensionY*runif(numberPeople)
plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,dimensionX),ylim=c(0,dimensionY))
for(i in 1:10000) {
    for(j in 1:numberPeople) {
       ang <- atan((y[j]-5)/(10-x[j]))
       x[j]<-x[j]+velocity*varianzavelocidad*cos(ang)
       y[j]<-y[j]-velocity*varianzavelocidad*sin(ang)
    }
if(X[j1] = X[J2] && Y[J1] = Y[J2]) {
 //MAKE THE DOTS CHOOSE BETWEEN THE STRONGEST //using strength value
} else() { they keep on going }
    x[x>10]=10
    plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,dimensionX),ylim=c(0,dimensionY)) 
}
```

I have tried downloading foreach function but honestly havent been able to find a way to use it correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please reduce your question to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier for other people to answer this question.

Comment: foreach function is not what you need right now.  Perhaps later.  You need to consider what's involved in testing two people to see if they are going to collide.  You only have 20 people right now, so testing person 1 against persons 2:20 and person 2 against persons 3:20 is tractable.

Comment: Thanks! i have edited what was suggested to do so! First time posting

Comment: Indeed perhaps foreach is not what i currently need right now, @AlexBrown, am sorry if i misunderstand, but with the code people always will collide unless i find a way to control their path, if am not wrong you suggesting me to improve the code only for two people and test it?

Comment: If suggesting that an initial implementation might consider each possible interaction between people by picking person 1, person 2 and resolving, and proceeding through all remaining pairs up to person 19, 20.  There will be comb(20,2) such pairs.

Comment: Wolfram says that's 190 pairs.

Comment: It won't be perfect, since it will fail to take into account movement decisions taken in later pairs when considering earlier pairs, but will get you started.